# How does a mantissa of 0 in IEEE 754 s=give a value which isn't 0

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

Trying to understand the IEEE 754 format a little better but getting a little stuck on one particular thing. When the mantissa is 0, but the exponent is not, how does it not equal 0?

For example 00111111100000000000000000000000 equals 1. Why? I fear I have missed something in my learning.

Comment: Wait, think I might have found it, is it because the mantissa always leads with a 1, even though it isn't stored, simply implied.

Comment: Yes, you've got it. An exponent of 0 is a special case that skips the leading 1. I've always thought that was a very clever feature, a way to get a free bit of precision.